# replicating a histogram with density estimation: can't solve the x and y axes

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, density-plot, geom

[original graph to be replicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDfVJ.png)
[the attempt at replication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM756.png)
I'm a beginner doing some extra credit for a lab by making graphs in R instead of the software we were given to automatically generate them. The first graph was made by that software, which is what I'm trying to recreate. It seems I'm heading in the right direction since the shape of the curve is right, but the data doesn't line up with the x and y axes correctly.

I'm pretty sure a log function is involved because that's how I got the right shape, but taking the log of the x axis data and/or scaling the x axis with log10 hasn't given me the right results. This is what I have for the graph I've been working on (it seems like the closest I've gotten to replication):

```
Interpellet <- ggplot(Teach_Back_1_FED3, aes(x=minutes)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), fill='blue') +
    geom_density() +
    scale_x_log10() +
    labs(x='Minutes Between Pellets', y='Density Estimation', title='Interpellet Intervals')
```

Note: I'm using the same csv for both so it's the same data.

Comment: I think you've got the right idea, but the data used in the original plot and the one used in your replication don't look to be the same.  You've got lots of density around 0.1 on the log scale and there is no data there on the plot you're trying to replicate.

Comment: If that's supposed to be the same data, then maybe the graph you're trying to replicate does something strange like round any values less than 1 up to 1. Because your `ggplot` graph clearly shows values around and even below 0.1, but the "original graph" appears to have a minimum >= 1.

Comment: You can use `binwidth = 0.1` in your call to `geom_histogram()` to ensure that you get comparable bin size. It's not going to solve the problem, but you'll be one step closer.